# Creating a 2D rendered D&D dungeon map in HTML, JS, and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am a beginner developer that is in first year at university. I really like coding and never stop challenging myself as i believe that, to learn coding, regularly exercising is the key.

And here i am stucking to the last one i throw myself, my goal is to create a dynamic 2D rendered D&D dungeon map that would let my players evolve in my dungeons together. As we're seprated by hundred and hundred of kilometers, thus we cannot play together (or at very rare occasions). Which is my principal motivation of doing so.

I've been having a hard time for the past two or three months to get any steps in the right direction.

At first i planned out the way i would construct the code and three major steps quite imposed themselves to me :

-First, i will create a tab in js that would represent the general layout of the dungeon (which i would manually recreate according to the dungeon's map i drew beforehand), the tab would be composed of numbers and each number would represent a specific object. For exemple, zero would be the walls (unwalkable area); One would be the tiles composing the rooms and corridors as the walkable areas; Two would be the doors; Three would be the chests and so on !

-Secondly, i shall create variables with the name of the characters that my friends play with. Letting them select their avatar before truly entering the dungeon by clicking on a button with the name of the character on it and assigning their computers onclick. The characters would have a certain value, for exemple the character called "Eowyn" would have a value of twenty, thus the code will update the tiles with the value of the character to accurately track them down on the map

-then, i shall find a way to display the areas one by one. And even before, finding a way to make the code realise the distinctions between all elements as rooms, corridors, etc... (you might realise i havn't reached that step with how few my ideas and explanations are written, this is all a mess in my head).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you are trying to recreate something like https://tarrasque.io/ but assuming that I am wrong here is the best I can come up with from your question.

> -First, i will create a tab in js that would represent the general layout of the dungeon (which i would manually recreate according to the dungeon's map i drew beforehand), the tab would be composed of numbers and each number would represent a specific object. For exemple, zero would be the walls (unwalkable area); One would be the tiles composing the rooms and corridors as the walkable areas; Two would be the doors; Three would be the chests and so on !

To do this I would suggest you use a nested array that could represent your visible area. If you assume that *most* characters in DnD 5e have somewhere between 20 and 60 feet of vision while in indoors, you can then assume that the visible area would not need to exceed 60 feet on any one side. If you use a 5 foot square, then you could use a nested array that is 12 'squares' to a side.

This would also easily allow you to choose what to show your Players as a function of distance from their position. (use the distance on a coordinate plane formula and replace X and y with Column and Row

> The distance between two points ( x 1 , y 1 ) and ( x 2 , y 2 ) can be
> defined as d = ( x 2 − x 1 ) 2 + ( y 2 − y 1 ) 2

Assuming that you use the nested arrays, and limit the number of squares visible on any screen, it would not be dificult to use a bunch of divs with fixed height and width to visually represent your 'grid.' That way rather than just having numbers to look at, you could assign a background image to each div based on what it was, and actually have a map. Using bootstrap 5's non-fluid container and then creating fixed-height rows would facilitate this rather nicely.

If you did this overlaying a different background image onto a div to represent your players would not be difficult.

However, all of this heavily depends on your ability to successfully code a backend for all of this that coordinates all of the computers connected to it and allows for multiple controllers to change the locations of various assets and deal with conflicting distances for rendering in the new squares, and a horrendous list of other issues, that frankly, I do not think I am qualified to try and explain solutions to.

If you still intend to go forward with this project your best bet is probably to use node.js, though personally, I would recommend PHP and MySQL. As for doing this with NO backend, I do not think it is possible, but I may be wrong.

I hope this has been helpful in some way, and worst-case scenario, there are several good examples of what you are trying to do that you can find and try to learn from just by googling.